# Google API auth2 SignIn: Enforce user to enter password every time

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin

I am using google JavaScript sign-in for web site in our web application. Everything is working the way it is supposed to be, however i would like to force the user to enter his password every time whenever he selects google sign-in method. At the moment, google password prompt is skipped, if same user is signed in chrome or in same browser.

Kindly confirm if it is do-able and how.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code